# binding ng-click to option values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I want a particular function to be called when anything is selected from a given dropdown. That function needs as an argument the value of the option selected. So far this is what I have got :

```
    <label class="control-label col-lg-3">Action Type</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <select class="form-control" id="type" >
            <option value="">Please Select</option>
            <option value="SCHEDULE" ng-click="getHtml(/*SCHEDULE*/)">
                SCHEDULE
            </option>
            <option value="HTTP" ng-click="getHtml(/*HTTP*/)" >
                HTTP
            </option>
            <option value="RMQ" ng-click="getHtml(/*RMQ*/)">
                RMQ
            </option>
            <option value="WFE" ng-click="getHtml(/*WFE*/)">
                WFE
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

However this does not seem to be working. Can someone please help?

The method is in the controller as:

```
$scope.getHtml=function(option){
        console.log("sent type is: "+type);
        var type=$('#type').val();
        //BLAH BLAH...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) here,

**first** assign a model to `select`

`ng-model="modelName"` the `modelName` is a `scope variable` which has the value of select box,

**second** remove the  `ng-click="getHtml..)` from `options`.

and using `ng-change` you can call a controller function with the value of `modelName` variable when the select box changing its value.

```
<select class="form-control" id="type" ng-change="getHtml(modelName)" ng-model="modelName">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="SCHEDULE">
            SCHEDULE
        </option>
       .....
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`ngChange`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) and [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directive on select element.

> ngChange: Evaluate the given expression when the user changes the input.

*Example*

```
<select class="form-control" id="type" ng-model='type' ng-change="getHtml(type)">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="SCHEDULE">SCHEDULE</option>
    <option value="HTTP">HTTP</option>
    <option value="RMQ">RMQ</option>
    <option value="WFE">WFE</option>
</select>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/djq2apna/)